# ES6: Applying function as class method

Tags: javascript, class, syntax, ecmascript-6

I'm migrating a project from CoffeeScript to ES6 (using 6to5 and Browserify), and am running into possibly a limitation or maybe I just don't know the proper syntax. In CoffeeScript I could do this:

```
class SomeView extends BaseView
    triggerMethod: Marionette.triggerMethod
```

How do I express this in ES6 classes? I tried a couple of things, but it throws `Unexpected token` errors no matter what I try. This for example:

```
let { triggerMethod } = Marionette;

class SomeView extends BaseView {
    triggerMethod, // doesn't work
    triggerMethod: Marionette.triggerMethod // doesn't work
}
```

Now I can achieve this by setting it in the constructor (`this.triggerMethod = Marionette.triggerMethod`), but it feels a bit ugly to me (just a preference in coding style I guess). Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't declare properties in ES6 classes, only methods and static methods (see [here](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-class-definitions) for syntax of class declaration, pay attention to *ClassElement*). So any of the following examples will be wrong:

```
class A {
    method1: B.someMethod  // wrong!
    method2: function() {} // wrong!
    method3: () => {}      // wrong!
}
```

You have several variants to handle your problem:

1. Use getter:

   ```
   class SomeView extends BaseView {
       get triggerMethod() { return Marionette.triggerMethod }
   }
   ```
2. Call `Marionette.triggerMethod` from `triggerMethod` of `SomeView` class:

   ```
   class SomeView extends BaseView {
       triggerMethod() { 
           Marionette.triggerMethod.apply(this, arguments);
       }
   }
   ```
3. Add `triggerMethod` to the prototype of `SomeView` after class declaration:

   ```
   class SomeView extends BaseView {
       //.. some class declaration
   }
   SomeView.prototype.triggerMethod = Marionette.triggerMethod;
   ```

   or with `Object.assign`:

   ```
   class SomeView extends BaseView {
       //.. some class declaration
   }

   Object.assign(SomeView.prototype, {
     triggerMethod: Marionette.triggerMethod
     // ... some another methods
   });
   ```
4. What you already did - add `Marionette.triggerMethod` to the `this`. But you must be aware that in that case `triggerMethod` will be kept in the object itself, not in its prototype. Example:

   ```
   class SomeView extends BaseView {
       constructor() {
         this.triggerMethod =  Marionette.triggerMethod
         // ...
       }
   }
   ```

That's all you can do. I think the first and second variants are the best choices for your case, but it's a matter of taste.

Comment: in this case ```Marionette.triggerMethod.apply(this, arguments);``` it fails because **Marionette.triggerMethod** is undefined. It sees my class Marionette, but when i try access triggerMethod - it's not available. As well i tried ```(new Marionette).triggerMethod.apply(this, args)``` it executes but it doesnt see **this** is not reassigned from needed class scope

Answer (score -1):

If I got this right you can define class methods this way:

```
class SomeView extends BaseView {
    triggerMethod(){
      Marionette.triggerMethod; 
   }
}
```

Pretty much the same as in coffeeScript, but some braces are required.
I haven't tried this, but see http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:classes

Comment: The way you defined it, `triggerMethod` doesn't really do anything. It references `Marionette.triggerMethod`, but it doesn't execute it.