# how redefine 'this' and reuse another class's method. Polymorphism

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I would love to make polymorphisme in js with classes reassigning **this**.

I have one class simplified to this:

```
class First{
  method1 = function(aVar) { this.list.map (e => e === aVar)}
}
```

and another class which is already has inharitance from another Parent class:

```
class Second extends Parent{
  constructor(){
    this.list = ['some elements'];
    this.method1 = First.method1.apply(this, arguments)
}
```

The Parent cannot be extended from the First;
When i run *Second* it throws an error: *apply* cannot be applied to **method1** because it's undefiend, 
But when i create an instance it losts ***Second's this*** scope :

```
class Second extends Parent{
  constructor(){
    this.list = ['some elements'];
    this.method1 = (new First).method1.apply(this, arguments)
}
```

Also i need to provide arguments to First.method1

i tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28195225/9277453) but that wasnt working

Comment: Don't use class fields to define methods, use a normal method definition instead.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with `method1` on your `Second` class? Please show the intended usage as well. It's unclear what those `arguments` are doing there (where `First`'s `method1` doesn't even take any), and what you expect the `this.list` to resolve to.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that the `.apply()` fires the function, and you don't want to fire the function, you want to *create* a function with changed `this` context. To do so, you want to use a `.bind()` method which creates a function but does not fire it. Look at this code:

```js
class First {
 
  method1() {
    this.list.map(e => e)
    console.log('I got called');
  }
  
  method2() {
    return this.list;
  }
}

class Parent {}

class Second extends Parent {
  constructor(){
    super();
    
    this.list = ['second class list'];
    this.method1 = (new First()).method1.bind(this)
    
    this.theList = (new First()).method2.apply(this);
  }
}

const sec = new Second();
sec.method1();
console.log(sec.theList);
```

So the `method1` in the `Second` class is a copy of the method with the same name from class `First`. It's created using `bind()` and changed `this` to the `Second` class context.

However, the `theList` field in the `Second` class is a result of *invoking* the `method2()` from the `First` class with changed `this` context. It is not a function, it's a result of the function.

See the difference?